# (Unity) Изменить программно normalColor InputField

Tags: unity3d

Есть метод, который при наведении курсора мышки должен изменять normalColor всех дочерних элементов, вложенных в объект, на котором висит скрипт. Содержание метода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject child = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            if (child !=null) {
                // первый вариант изменения цвета
                child.GetComponent<Graphic>().color = new Color(207, 209, 214, 255);
                //второй вариант изменения цвета
                Color newColor = new Color(207, 209, 214, 255);
                ColorBlock cb = child.GetComponent<InputField>().colors;
                cb.normalColor = newColor;
                Debug.Log(child.GetComponent<Graphic>().color);
            }

        }
```

Т.е. все объекты, вложенные в объект, на который наведен курсор мышки, это - InputField-ы.

```
Debug.Log(child.GetComponent<Graphic>().color);
```

в лог выводит переданные значения цвета, хотя сам цвет дочерних inputfield не меняется (ни в первом, ни во втором варианте), почему?

На родительский объект добавлен скрипт `Event Trigger` с данным методом.

Как же изменить цвет дочерних элементов?

Comment: Если Вам нужно изменить цвет поля `normalColor`, то попробуйте так:  `var chieldInput = child.GetComponent<InputField>(); if (chieldInput != null) { var colors = chieldInput.colors; colors.normalColor = new Color(207, 209, 214, 255); chieldInput.colors = colors; }`

Comment: ...короче говоря, вашему `InputField` нужно присвоить измененную структуру `ColorBlock`.

Comment: @Александр Даниловский, второй вариант кода взяла из API [ссылка](https://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.5/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ColorBlock-normalColor.html). Ваш вариант тоже не сработал. Попробовала создать новую сцену, добавить на нее объект и программно изменить его цвет. Оказалось, что child.GetComponent<Graphic>().color = new Color(207, 209, 214, 255); меняет цвет, только цвет нужно указывать в формате Vector 4, т.е. так:  child.GetComponent<Graphic>().color = new Color(0.812f, 0.820f, 0.839f, 1);

Comment: соответственно второй вариант тоже верный, только если изменить формат цвета на RGB 0-1.0: ` for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject child = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            if (child != null)
            { 
                Color newColor = new Color(0.812f, 0.820f, 0.839f, 1);
                ColorBlock cb = child.GetComponent<InputField>().colors;
                cb.normalColor = newColor;
                child.GetComponent<InputField>().colors = cb;               
            }

        }`

Comment: @Volha, если вы самостоятельно нашли ответ на свой вопрос - оформите ответ, возможно, кому-то это пригодится в будущем.